# Forms Authentication and All fine except blank datavalue field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create and read a forms authentication cookie in a c# web app that I am developing.

I create the ticket

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "myData", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), true, "Hello");

// Now encrypt the ticket.
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,encryptedTicket);
```

// Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

Then when I retrieve the ticket using:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)
```

I can see authTicket now has all of the data, cookie creation date, expiration date, name="mydata"... etc.

But there is nothing in the dataValue... I am expecting "Hello" to be there.

When I debug, I can see it is in the ticket right before encryption... it is getting lost in the decryption I suppose?

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the cookie you use the [FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiename.aspx) property while when you read it you use the `cookieName` variable. Are you sure that both point to the same cookie? Also verify with FireBug that the value in the cookie is the same as the one you see when you debug.

Comment: I am assuming that it is the correct cookie... I look at the creation time right before encrypt and it matches on the decrypt side... so I figure that is the correct cookiename.  Everything looks good on the ticket except the datavalue field is blank. It is very strange.

Comment: There must be something overwriting the initial cookie value. You can confirm this with FireBug. If you have the same cookie value when you decrypt you will get the correct string in the `UserData` property of the decrypted ticket. I've just executed your code sequentially in a console application and everything was fine.

Comment: Best I can tell everything looks good, I can see the cookin in firebug but it is encrypted so I can't see what the value is.  on the retrieval side, I can see the ticket before decryption and datavalue field has an encrypted string but after the decrypt function, the field is blank.  I am perplexed.  Could there be a setting somewhere that I am not aware of preventing the datavalue field from coming through?

Comment: So you confirm that the string you see while debugging for `authCookie.Value` is exactly the same as the one you pass to the `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt` function?

Comment: hmm.... on encrypt authcookie.value =11E4BA64EFB.........
on decyrption authcookie.value = C0E87E010C8C9......

I can't see anywhere that I am overwriting this... anyway to track that down you think?

Comment: @sdmiller - do you have any cookie handling code in your global.asax? it's possible the cookie has already been accessed and accidentally overwritten.

Comment: I don't think I have a global.asax file loaded in the project. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Ok... The cookie is being changed somewhere after execution has finished or right before page load.... The times are not matching up on the debugger. WHen I step through, when it is created is about 10 seconds earlier than the decrypted one... 10 seconds is about the time it take for me to step through and page reloads.  I can't find any place in my code where it would set a cookie other than my one write function.

Comment: Found the problem  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username,false), is causing the problem. Not sure how to fix it... I thought that this was just a session redirect for users loggin in.

Comment: No, this also sets the cookie and replaces the original value. Don't call this method if you are going to add the authentication cookie manually. Do the redirect yourself upon successful login.

Comment: Rock on.. it works!!! Only problem I have now is, the cookie is not retained if you close the browser.... I have persistent set to true, any ideas?

Comment: You set persistent on the ticket but not on the cookie. Try setting an expiration date: `authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)`.

Comment: You are the Man Darin... It is all working now!

Thanks a whole lot guys... I have been banging my head over this!

Answer (score 0):

Try using SetAuthCookie(authCookie) instead of REsponse.Cookies.Add(authCookie).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx

Comment: That just seems to set authorized user and doesn't seem to effect the ticket in any way. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try decrypting the ticket before and after you add it to the cookie to make sure there is not a "tolerated" exception happening during either of the processes. Are there any messages in the event log indicating possible system errors at the server level that may not have been caught by the exception handling?

Comment: I started decrypting the cookie in different spots in my code after pushing the cookie and everything is fine until page reload.  I step through the code all the way through and right at the end it is still good, first thing after page load... there is nothing in the datavalue field and the encryption string for data field is different.  I have no clue as to why!  Something in IIS?